# Meteor- React: Withtracker not running when subscribe

Tags: reactjs, meteor

I am trying to fetch documents from a collection which matches the id that the user enters in a form. So what I am doing is subscribing to the publication whenever the input changes. This works. My issue is that when the user enters an id which matches, The props of withtracker gets filled with the data but the second time the user tries with an id that doesn't match at all the props doesn't changes, the previous data are still showing.

Here is my withtracker code

```
export default PlantDetailsContainer = withTracker(() => {
    Meteor.subscribe('stickerById', null);
    return {
      stickeringDetails: Sticker.findOne()
    }
})(AddPlantDetails);
```

Here is my function that calling on user input change

```
handleIdChange = (e) => {
    Meteor.subscribe('stickerById', parseInt(e.target.value));
  }
```

Here is my publication code

```
Meteor.publish('stickerById', function stickerByIdPublication(id) {
        return Sticker.find({ids: {"$in": [id]}});
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to resubscribe every time the value changes.

Meteor does some magic inside the `withTracker` method to set up reactivity. So make sure you pass in the id at that point (usually from a route parameter).

Not sure where the id is coming from - is the user entering it, or is it a pull-down?

Comment: The id is entering by the user. How can I pass the id from the component to withTracker

Comment: Pass the id into the React component when you render it, eg

`<MyPlantContainer id={stickerId}/>`

Assuming that you are using hooks, and `stickerId` is a state value

Comment: I will get the id only from user inputs this happens after component renders. So I will have to create a child component and each time user inputs the data I have to render the child component. Right?